# android output stream flush issue

Tags: java, android, socketchannel

I am developing one android application for server emulation(like *Online terminal*) using **SocketChannel(Java Native)** for stream connection. But in the application I am trying to flush the output stream every time after I send the data to the server. When I am doing that The flush method taking 2 to 4 seconds for it's execution in Nougat and above. And I tested that scenario with 5 different mobiles. Also in Marshmallow I tested the same scenario in 2 different mobiles that's work fine.

Comment: BufferedOutputStream

Comment: so your BufferedOutputStream is wrong means?

Comment: Then what can I use ? Could you please help me regarding that issue